# Return message: if no results

Tags: channel-entries, ifelse

I am trying to do something which I suspect is quite simple.

I am referencing a channel field to rerun results to populate a series of check boxes. If there are no results I wish to say 'There are no results".

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="sales" disable="categories|category-fields|member-data|pagination" status="open" sort="asc"} 
    <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" value="{postcode1}">
       {postcode1}
    </label>
    {if no_results}Sorry, No Results{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any thoughts?

Niall

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to add `require_entry="yes"` as a parameter on your opening `channel:entries` tag and your code should work as expected.

See the [documentation on that here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#require-entry).

Comment: Maybe worth noting that if you don't have `require_entry="yes"`, the entries tag will default to showing the most recent entries.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you are using this in conjunction with Croxton's ifelse plugin (I see you tagged your question with ifelse)? If so, you need to use the {no_results}{/no_results} tag pair instead of the if statement you are using.